# D3.js plot: SVG z-order of foreignelement not working in firefox

Tags: html, svg, d3.js

I have a basic SVG scatter plot with `d3.js` and want to have an output paragraph at a fixed position in the plot. Initially, the paragraph shows some basic usage text but once the user interacts with the plot, the paragraph should show some output that includes `html` features such as `<sub>` tags and special symbols.

I implemented that paragraph as a `foreignobject` in the SVG of a rather big size to include the initial text. It works fine in Safari and Chrome, but fails in Firefox: the `foreignobject` overlaps with the dots and makes it impossible to hover over them. Any idea how to fix that or how to implement it avoiding these issues?

See example code below or [this bl.ock.org](http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/022de0b5899d42f78b4b) - remember it works fine in Safari but doesn't work in Firefox:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Visualization</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/mbostock/d3/master/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <style media="screen" type="text/css">
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: black;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges
    }

    .axis text {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .clicktext {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 11px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        /* test data set */
        var dataset = []; 
        for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            dataset.push({x:Math.random() * 30,y:Math.random() * 30});
        }

        /* extend and plot sizes */     
        var w = 500;
        var h = 300;
        var dot;
        var padding  = 60;
        var def_c_sz = 5;

        /* Description text */
        var pclick_txt = '<b>Usage</b><br/>'+
            '<br>text test text text test text<br/>'+
            'text test text text test text text test text text test text text test text';

        /* axes limits */
        var x0  = 0.;
        var x1  = 30.;
        var y0  = 0;
        var y1  = 30;

        /* the SVG canvas for the plot */   
        var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
            .attr('width',w)
            .attr('height',h)
            .attr('float','left');

        /* the scales */
        var xscale = d3.scale.linear();
        var yscale = d3.scale.linear();
        xscale.range([padding,w-padding]).domain([x0,x1]);
        yscale.range([h-padding,padding]).domain([y0,y1]);

        /*  CREATE AXES AND PARAGRAPH */
        function addaxes(){

            /* add the output paragraph */              
            pclick=svg.append("foreignObject")
                .attr("x",xscale(x0))
                .attr("y",yscale(y1))
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height",h)
              .append("xhtml:body")
              .append("p")
                .attr('class','clicktext label')
                .attr('style','background-color:rgba(125,125,125,0.75);padding:'+padding/5+'px;font-size:x-small;')
                .html(pclick_txt); 

            /* Add x-axis */
            var xaxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .orient('bottom')
                .scale(xscale);
            xaxis.tickFormat(d3.format('n'));

            svg.append('g')
                .attr('class','axis')
                .attr('transform','translate(0,'+(h-padding)+')')
                .call(xaxis);

            /* Add y-axis */            
            var yaxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .orient('left')
                .scale(yscale)
            svg.append('g')
                .attr('class','axis')
                .attr('transform','translate('+(padding)+',0)')
                .call(yaxis);
        }

        circles = svg.selectAll(".dots").data(dataset);
        circlesE = circles.enter().append("circle").attr("class","dots");
        circlesE
            .attr("cx",function(d){return xscale(d.x)})
            .attr("cy",function(d){return yscale(d.y)})
            .attr("r",def_c_sz)
            .attr("fill","orange")
            .on("mouseover",mouseover)
            .on("mouseout",mouseout);

        /* call axes after the dots have been drawn */
        addaxes();

        /* define callbacks */
        function mouseover(d){ 
            dot = d3.select(this);
            dot.transition()
                .duration(100)
                .attr('r',2*def_c_sz);
            pclick.attr('style','background-color:transparent;padding:'+0+'px;font-size:x-small;')
                .html(function(d){return '<b>y = '+dot.data()[0].y+'</b>'});
        }

        function mouseout(){ 
            d3.select(this)
                .transition()
                .duration(700)
                .attr('r',def_c_sz);
            pclick.attr('style','background-color:transparent;padding:'+0+'px;font-size:x-small;')
                .html('<b>not hovering :-(</b>');
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Draw the foreignObject before the dots or make it pointer-events:none (in which case you won't be able to select the text but you will be able to hover the dots). Whatever Safari is doing seems wrong.

Comment: putting the points up front doesn't help as I want the text in front of the points but setting the style of the foreignobject was exactly what I was looking for. If you post it as answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the attribute pointer-events="none" to the foreignObject element it will become transparent to mouse clicks and so you'll be able to hover the dots. A side effect will be that you won't be able to select the text though.